# Background image below the div with background color property

Tags: html, css, html5-canvas, z-index

I'm trying to show background image below two `div`s with `background-color` property.
I tried playing with `z-index` and `position: relative` but so far did not succeed.
Image just not visible below this two `div`s.

CSS:

```
.bgImage {
background-image: url('../images/footer_bg.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: top center;
z-index: 999;
position: relative;
}

footer .bgColor1 {
background-color: #3E3E3E;
min-height: 223px;
overflow: hidden;
z-index: 0;
position: relative;
}
footer .bgColor2 {
background-color: #819808;
min-height: 223px;
overflow: hidden;
z-index: 0;
position: relative;
}
```

HTML:

```
<footer class="bgImage">
  <div class="bgColor1"></div>
  <div class="bgColor2"></div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Add a negative `z-index` to your inner DIVs:
- Remove the `z-index` from the parent DIV

([example](http://jsfiddle.net/TrWvr/))

This will place the inner DIVs below their parent. If you're interested in understanding how this works [read this page on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index). Basically you have to avoid creating a local stacking context on the parent element that you want placed above (`z-index` and a few other properties create a stacking context).

Answer (score 0):

Try using `rgba(#,#,#,0.5);` to specify colours where # is a number from 0 to 255 to specify the colour. The ending 0.5 is for 50% opacity.